# Get ERC20token balance in solidity

Tags: solidity

Such as ERC20token smartcontract, just is the token balance of accounts, i want to make a smart contract to use token contract address and account address to find out the token balance of different accounts or different token

Answer (score 4):

Get this: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol

Then,

```
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract Checker {

  function checkBal(address token, address holder) public view returns(uint) {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(token);
    return token.balanceOf(holder);
  }
}
```

That will let you check the balance of any address in any ERC20 token contract you want to inspect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks,it worked ,it's helpful for me

Comment: Awesome. The customary forms of thanks are upvotes and accept so that others might find the answer ;-)